# Finding Triangle's Angle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Find the value of $x$ if the area is $42\;\mathrm{cm}^2$.

The triangle is not right angled or an isosceles.

$X$ is the angle in the bottom left corner of the triangle that I need to find.

The left side of the triangle is $7\;\mathrm{cm}$ in length and the bottom length is $13\;\mathrm{cm}$.

I know that I have to use Heron's formula to work this out but to do this, I need to first find the semi perimeter. However, I can't find the semi perimeter because the right side length is not given, but instead the whole area of the triangle is given ($42\;\mathrm{cm}^2$). I'm really confused on how I should work this whole question out.

Comment: $\text{Area}=\frac{ab\sin(C)}{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are two sides and $C$ is the angle in between. From your description it seems to be that you have the lengths of the two sides adjacent to the angle $X$, do you?

Comment: @Pp.. you should have posted that as an answer

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use the relation Area = Base * height / 2 and sin(x).

Please see:

[image]

1. find h using 42 = 13 * h / 2
2. substitute h into sin(x) = h / 7

Hope this help!

Comment: If you click on the picture in the editing menu, you can upload your photograph.  I took a screenshot of your diagram, edited it for size, then uploaded it.

Comment: It looks like you meant $\sin x = \dfrac{h}{7}$.

Comment: Sorry that I need 50 reputation to upload picture. Thanks for the upvotes I can do it now.
Thanks N.F. Taussig, corrected.